# Symfony2 choice field : empty value

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm stumbling upon a really simple question and I can't find out what I'm doing wrong :

I have an entity Post which *can* have a type, in my class declaration :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $type;
```

Then I want a form to create Posts : 
In my PostType::buildForm() function :

```
$builder->add('type', 'choice', array(
        'empty_data' => null,
        'empty_value' => 'No type',
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => true,
        'choices' => \MyBundle\Entity\Application\Post::getTypes(), /* returns array('TYPE1' => 'TYPE_1', 'TYPE2' => 'TYPE_2', ...) */
        'required' => true,))
```

The plan is to have a radio list with :

- Type 1
- Type 2
- Type 3
- No type

But it seems like if I choose the option 'No type', the form won't validate, without giving any explicit error. Same thing happens with 'required' => false, with 'placeholder' instead of 'empty_value', ...

Can you spot my mistake ?
What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.7.1 by the way

Comment: Does the error occur only when you choose "No type"? I mean, are you sure another field isn't invalidating the form ?

Comment: Yes, if I choose any other Type the form will validate

Comment: Do you display all errors ? Or just the ones attached to fields ? Maybe the form itself has error. Can you post the dump of $form->gerErrors()?

Comment: I tried removing 'empty_data', setting 'empty_data' => '', even removing 'empty_value', 'empty_data' and setting required => false to let symfony handle the "empty" choice.
Still the same error occurs when selecting the "None" choice..

Comment: Okay, the errors dump for the form gives me an empty array :
private 'errors' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty

Still, the $form->isValid() returns false...

Comment: Have you tried with a dropdown list, just to check ?

Comment: Wow ! Working with a select list. I'll have a look on my custom twig fields...

Comment: Okay, I figured it out... It was coming from a {% if value is not empty %} value="{{value}}" {% endif %} in my twig template, which should be value="{{value}}" (even if value is empty...).
What should I do ? answer my own question ?

Comment: You can answer your own question, it might help somebody else later.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Hakim ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake didn't come from the Type or the Entity, it came from the twig widgets overloading.

I was not displaying the `value=""` if `{{ value }}` was empty.

Make sure `value=""` is inside your "None" input radio tag, and in your other input radio tags aswell, of course !
Hope it helps someone ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an empty value on a choice field type and have it required.
You are saying it must exist but may be empty, a contradiction.

It will work if you drop the `'required' => true`

Comment: Thanks, but same thing happens without required => true. Doesnt seem to change anything